# Is it valid to use an EF-linq-query-result after the DbContext is disposed?

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I have all logic functions inside the using-DbContext scope.
For future code I want to write (and maybe refactoring) I considered to change it into this form, where I load the list using the context, and dispose it immediately after it and use the list for further computations.

```
Test()
{
    var list = (List<MyObject>)null;

    using( var ctx = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        list = ctx.MyTable.ToList();
    }

    // is the list guaranteed to be unchanged?
    foreach( var item in list )
    {

    }
}
```

The only difference (as I would guess) is that the EF dropped the cache for the objects, so I cannot update the database anylonger (what I usually do not want/use anyways).

Is it safe to use the list after the context has been disposed?

Comment: Tbh, it usually lines up with other `var` declarations, so its more readable. But you are right, on single declarations like this, I also go with the regular one.

Comment: The question is a bit odd. How do you want to use a result of an EF-query at all if not in this way? It would make more sense to ask if it would work without `ToList`. The answer is "No". Because the context is disposed after the using.

Comment: Declare the list as `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and see what happens if you remove the `ToList`. You will get an exception at the `foreach`. The `ToList` actually executes the _deferred executed_ LINQ query. The result will be loaded into memory, there's no relation to the database anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, Yes. Once you call ToList() the object should be detached from EF but will still have any tracking proxies attached to it that have been defined by EF.

No EF stuff will work on it though, like Lazy loading etc...